# Spanning tree with equally separated edge weights

Tags: graphs, optimization, approximation, spanning-trees, clustering

I have a fully-connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with edge weights $w(v)\in\mathbb{R};v\in V$ and I need to find a spanning tree $T=(V_t\subseteq V,E_t\subseteq E)$ where the set of edge weights in the tree have as close as possible to equal separation. We quantify the notion of *equal separation* by minimizing the variance of difference between weights: $minimize: Var\left(\Delta(E_t)\right)$, where $Var$ is the variance function and $\Delta(E')=\{|w(e_1)-w(e_2)|, ..., |w(e_{n-1})-w(e_n)|\}$ where $e_i\in E'$ and $E'\subseteq E$ is a list of edges sorted by weight.

So an optimal solution to this problem will be an instance of $T$ such that $T$ is a spanning tree and $Var(\Delta(E_t))$ is the minimum over all possible spanning trees of $G$.

I have two ideas for this:

**1)** Pick a random starting node and perform a best-first spanning search, prioritizing the OPEN list for each $e'\in OPEN$ by $Var\left(\Delta(E_t \cup {e'})\right)$ where $E_t$ is the set of edges chosen so far in the search.

**2)** Find $n-1$ clusters of edges using a clustering algorithm such as k-means clustering based on $w(e)$ for all $e\in E$. Then (somehow) find a spanning tree that includes exactly one element from each of the $k$ cluster sets. (I think this might not work without doing something fancy to ensure that a spanning tree can actually be chosen from the sets.)

I coded up 1) and found that although it yields a fairly decent approximation it is sub-optimal, even if I take the best tree over all trees starting from each of the $n$ vertices... I have not yet tried 2).

This smells NP-hard... Is there an algorithm to compute a spanning tree with  edge weights separated as equally as possible? (aside from brute-force?)

Comment: If a heuristic is good enough, maybe something worth trying would be to determine the median weight $d$, and then "fold back" all edge weights $w$ that are above $d$ to $d-w$, and run an MST algorithm as usual.  The resulting tree will tend to favour edges of extreme low or high weight.